# How do I add CSS font styles to PHP echos?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, row

How can I add different font-styles to different rows?

I want all of them to have a different font-style. For example:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo $row['Nimi']."<br>".$row['Kirjailija']."<br>".$row['ISBN']."<br>".$row['Kunto']."<br>".$row['Hinta']."€"."<br>".$row['Pvm'];
  echo "<br>"."<br>";
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not so good at php. But I gave a little try about it like this:

Slight modification to your code.. Adding a classing to each row!

```
i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
/* adding <span class="row1"> row2 etc.. using i */
  echo "<span class='row".i."'>".$row['Nimi']."<br>".$row['Kirjailija']."<br>".$row['ISBN']."<br>".$row['Kunto']."<br>".$row['Hinta']."€"."<br>".$row['Pvm'];
  echo "<br>"."<br></span>";
  i++;
 }
```

Giving Styles in css based on row names:

```
.row1{
 font-family: verdana;
}

.row2{
 font-family: arial;
}

etc..
```

I am repeating once again, I'm not sure about syntax.. I am posting this only to share the concept hoping that it should work! :)

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
style="font-family:verdana;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styling `<span style="color: red;">test</span>`, or use classes of css: `<span class="red-color">text</span>` with a css

```
.red-color{
    color: red;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

In general, it is better to use classes with an external css file - that would keep your code organized and scalable.

In your case it is possible to use inline style like:

```
echo "<span style=\"color: red; font-family: Arial\">" . $row['Nimi'] . "</span>" . "<span style=\"color: green; font-family: Verdana\">" . $row['Kirjailija'];
```

Also, it is not a good practice to use `<br />` now-a-days. Better wrap each text with a `<span>`, or a `<div>`